# HTML (js inside) page to pdf using HTML2PDF issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-to-pdf

I get into trouble when I want to change the html page to pdf using HTML2PDF. actually, i dont know what is going on with my code. but the error appears like this : 
[image]

to be clear, this is the code :

```html
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
include_once("config.php"); 
?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!-- Bagian halaman HTML yang akan konvert -->
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title><?php echo $judul; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
echo "<h1>".$judul."</h1>"; 
?>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
   
  
<script type="text/javascript">    
 google.charts.load('current', {packages:["orgchart"]});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Manager');https://jsfiddle.net/klometerz/zyq1rp81/#run
        data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');

        // For each orgchart box, provide the name, manager, and tooltip to show.
        data.addRows([
  
  <?php 
  include "inc/koneksi.php";
  $data = mysql_query("select * from t_chart");
  while($d = mysql_fetch_array($data))
  {
   echo "[{v:'".$d[id_chart]."', f:'".$d[f_chart];?></a><div style="color:red; size:11px; font-style:italic"><?php echo "<a href=edit_chart.php?id=".$d[id_chart].">".$d[batch_chart]."</a></div>'},'".$d[manager_chart]."', '".$d[tooltip_chart]."'],";
  }
  ?>
        
        ]);

        // Create the chart.
        var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        // Draw the chart, setting the allowHtml option to true for the tooltips.
        chart.draw(data, {allowHtml:true});
      }
   </script>
   
   <?php
echo $isi;
echo "<p align='right'>".$penulis."</p>";
?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$content = ob_get_clean();
 $content = '<page style="font-family: freeserif">'.nl2br($content).'</page>';
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
 try
 {
  $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('L','A4','en', false, 'ISO-8859-15',array(30, 0, 20, 0));
  $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
  $html2pdf->writeHTML($content, isset($_GET['vuehtml']));
  $html2pdf->Output('SO');
 }
 catch(HTML2PDF_exception $e) { echo $e; }
?>
```

please anybody can help me here solve this problem? i will be very appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Where does your <a> get opened ?? ` echo "[{v:'".$d[id_chart]."', f:'".$d[f_chart];?></a>`

Comment: thanks sir, but the error that appear is changing to be like i report

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message you posted suggests that HTML2PDF library does not support script tags in the html. You can remove the script tags from the html using regular expressions. For example:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<script[^>]*?>.*?<\/script>/si", "", $content);
```

The above line can be added just after the line:

```
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

The above code was taken from: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#76297.

Comment: This is not working, what I have to do with variable $text?

Comment: Well the script tag is causing problems with generating pdf. So it needs to be removed. The code I posted removes the script tag from the content of the page.  The variable $text contains the contents of the current page without the script tag. It can be used in the writeHTML method to generate the pdf